# Git status and local repo files

Tags: git

Say I've the following files in my project folder:

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
d.txt
e.txt
f.txt
```

Now i've done following operations on the files:

```
git add a.txt b.txt c.txt d.txt
git commit -m "added a.txt" a.txt
git commit -m "added b.txt" b.txt
```

Now when i do

```
git status
```

there are no files *a.txt, b.txt* listed.

Why doesn't Git status show these *a.txt, b.txt* files which are in the local repo now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ask for `status`, git compares the last commit with the index and with the working tree and lists the *differences*.

Right after you add and commit *a.txt* and *b.txt*, there are *no* differences with regard to them. They are now identical in all three places. That is exactly what add and commit *means*. So `git status` is silent about them.

If what you want to know is what files you’ve got in the latest commit or in the index, use `ls-tree` or `ls-files`. But in general, and with *a.txt* and *b.txt* in this instance, the rule is: you can *see* them in the working tree, and `git status` doesn’t mention them, and you haven’t told git to ignore them, so you *know* they are committed without being told.

Answer (score 1):

`git status` shows the files that are not included into your revision history.

Once you commit, now they are part of your history (as a commit).

From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status) :

> Displays paths that have differences between the index file and the
>   current HEAD commit

Recalling what i said; once you commit you will have your changes included into your HEAD (as a last commit). So you will see nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation of git status](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status) states, "`git status` displays paths that have differences between the index file and the current HEAD commit".

This means, if you've already committed files `a.txt` and `b.txt`, they are now **below** the HEAD commit, and the HEAD commit itself in the case of `b.txt` because it's the latest commit. Therefore, there is no difference in terms of these files to your local repo, and you shouldn't expect them to appear when running `git status`.